# What is the most efficient way to get hair off a bar of soap?

Tags: bathroom

Too often, thin, straight hairs get stuck to our bar of soap.

I usually use my fingernail to scrape them off, then wash them off my fingertips.  But even if I'm gentle, this seems to scrape up a lot of soap along with the hair.

What is the most efficient (in time and soap) method to remove hairs from a bar of soap?

Comment: My advice is to wait. About 20 years. Then your close-up vision will have deteriorated and you won't be able to see the hair. Out of sight, out of mind!

Comment: Use liquid soap, it's much better in every single way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bar of soap is dry, a lint remover will stick to the strand of thin hair but will not stick to the soap. Tap the hairy bar with the sticky roller before guests arrive.

If the bar of soap is wet, wait patiently for it to dry.

Answer (score 4):

The hairs are embedded (shallowly) in the soap. As you use the bar of soap, though, the outside layer of soap will come off.  So hold the bar of soap under running water. Slide your hands down the sides from top to bottom, so that the loose hairs move with the flowing water. You can even wrap your hand around the bar and squeeze it out the top of your fingers (but be sure to catch it with the other hand). Within just a few seconds, all the hairs should be washed off of the soap bar.